# Shiny error after packages update: Unknown `composition` type

Tags: r, shiny, xgboost, tidymodels

After some packages update, I'm no longer able to start my shiny application. The error I'm receiving it's not very clear:

> Warning: Error in : Internal error: Unknown composition type. 69:
> Error : Internal error: Unknown composition type.

I'm quite sure that this error is related to some update as, the same application works fine within another machine with the same R version (4.0) and the same Shiny version (booth are MACos).
Do some of you know how to trouble-shooting this?

Comment: Maybe start with a fresh R session, sequentially comment out R packages and see where you get different error messages. Then you can compare the package versions to the working computer. Or, if the app is not too big, you can set `browser`s at different places in the code to step through and see where the error happens. Also, I've found a similar error message mentioned here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modeltime/news/news.html

Comment: @starja the fresh install option is already performed without luck. Yes the break point is an options, just wondering if ther’s a way to have a better (more deeper) error message.

Comment: After some additional troubleshooting seems that the problem is related to predict() function with an xbgoost model trained with tidymodels.

Comment: The version of hardhat that just went to CRAN did contain a change around this `composition` argument, controlling the datatype that gets passed around internally. If you have different versions of hardhat locally where the model was trained and where you are deploying, this is likely a problem.

Comment: Confirm in the machine with shiny issues I've the latest version of hardhat (0.1.5) while in the machine with a working deploy of the same app I've got the older one (0.1.4)