# Tidymodels Error: Internal error: Unknown `composition` type

Tags: r, xgboost, tidymodels

This question is related to a previous question [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64834452/shiny-error-after-packages-update-unknown-composition-type).

I have trained XGB model using `tidymodels 0.1.1` and `xgboost 1.2.0.1`. I then saved the resulting model object using:

```
saveRDS(model.list, file = "*****.rds")
```

I did this 2 days ago. I have opened a new session today, on the same machine,  and loaded the saved model object using:

```
readRDS("*****.rds")
```

Using `predict()` on some new data I am getting this error:

```
Error: Internal error: Unknown `composition` type.
```

From the post referenced above it could be an issue with updating the packages, specifically `hardhat`. The time between creating, saving and then using the model is only 2 days. So it seems unlikely there has been another package update that has caused the same issue.

Does anyone know if it could be the saving and load of the model objects?

Comment: I have been trying to work around this issue for a few days and haven't managed it. Would an answer be to install an older version of hardhat?

Comment: Yes, it is possible/likely that the change in hardhat is what caused this; you can [read more about the `composition` type](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/11/tidymodels-sparse-support/) that was added within tidymodels. It seems like we didn't successfully account for models that were trained _before_ we added this new type. I think your best options are to retrain the model or use a solution like [renv](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/) to capture your model versions at training for prediction time.